# Can not Click the Items in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm using old way to create bottom navigation and using Fragment as well. 
When I starting design some view inside Fragment. Like Edit, TextBox or ScollView etc. Everything in Fragment are unclickable. 
(I had run the app on real device and emulator.
I can not use my mouse click the Textbox But I can input the text by using tab to reach the Textbox

Below is the function I use to open Fragment when I clicked navigation
(In my HomeActivity.kt)

```
private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Below is Xml of container
(In my Activity_Home.xml)

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>
```

Below is one of Fragment

```
class PersonalFragment : Fragment() {

    var Personal = getActivity()?.getApplicationContext();

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): PersonalFragment = PersonalFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false)
    }
}
```

Below is Xml of Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_select_photo_button"
            android:text="@string/UploadIMG"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_nickname"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_etext"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/hint_nickname"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uploadButton" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_birthday"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_etext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/hint_birthday"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="none"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_nickname" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share you fragment_personal.xml file as well?

Comment: @AkshayRaiyani sure

Comment: Just Add 
   android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
in your root ConstraintLayout, and check it.

Comment: @AkshayRaiyani Same my bro

Comment: comes no Keyboard, when you click in EdintText?

Comment: @anatoli nah nothing happened when i clicked it

Comment: remove `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` from `FrameLayout`

Comment: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` could also make the problems by clicking

Comment: @anatoli all remove and same :(

Answer (score 1):

override onCreateView as follows:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal, container, false)

    var button = view.findViewById(R.id.uploadButton)
    button.setOnClickListener(view ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    )

    return view
}
```

and rerun the app. by click on Button you should see **clicked**

Comment: I mean like Edit Text (Like User input his nickname)
I can not use my mouse click the Textbox
But I can input the text by using tab to reach the Textbox

Comment: Mouse? Do you use Emulator? Android has touch screen. Does Button click works?

Comment: Yeah ,I had test on Emulator and Real device both are unclickeable.
Button are in same situation
it look like something cover on it

Comment: Also Button not clickable? the fragment is not realy been loaded. try to remove `transaction.addToBackStack(null)`

Comment: same:( Maybe be sth wrong
Do you wanna check our Github ?